# nginx+PHP freezes on calls to same machine

Tags: php, windows, nginx

In response to a request, my php+nginx server makes several small calls to another server, iterating through a list. In development, this other server is the same machine and after X calls the server hangs, times out on the call and moves on to the next call, only to hang again later after another X calls.

It appears the server is trying to re-use/queue the call to the original http/php thread/connection, causing a lock. I determined that because:

- X is correlated to the number of "upstream" entries in the nginx configuration.
- Executing the same code from the console does not hang

The script to reproduce is

```
for ($i=1;$i<15;$i++){
        $search = file_get_contents('http://SAME-MACHINE/ANY-SCRIPT.PHP');
        var_dump($search);
}
```

The environment is Windows 10, Laragon (3.16/4.0) managing nginx (1.12/ 1.16) and php (7.2.18 / 7.2.20) .

- Increasing the number of nginx upstream entries only pushes the problem further in the process/iteration
- I'm not very familiar with nginx configuration and tried a few config directives to no effect.

Assuming a default round-robin behaviour, it seems to me nginx/php should know this "connection/thread" is busy and avoid it or quickly use another.

**unify.test.conf**

```
server {
 listen 80;
 listen 443 ssl;
    server_name unify.test *.unify.test 0a4ea695.ngrok.io;
 root "C:/Dev/GITs/unify/public/";

 index index.html index.htm index.php;

 location / {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        autoindex on;
 }

 location ~ \.php$ {
 include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
 fastcgi_pass php_upstream;     
 #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
 }

 charset utf-8;

 location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
 location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
 location ~ /\.ht {
 deny all;
 }
}
```

**fastcgi-php.conf**

```
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

**fastcgi.conf**

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

**php_upstream.conf**

```
# if you want to increase the number of PHP processes, put this line (without #) on usr/laragon.ini, under [nginx]
# [nginx]
# Upstream=5
upstream php_upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:9001 weight=1 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=1;
    server 127.0.0.1:9002 weight=1 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=1;
    server 127.0.0.1:9003 weight=1 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=1;
    server 127.0.0.1:9004 weight=1 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=1;
}
```

Comment: Assuming that you are using PHP-FPM - nginX will communicate with the master FPM process which should in turn create one child process per each request. The same child process will not be used to handle another HTTP request until it has finished the current request. The only way to break this is if there are more simultaneous HTTP requests than the available PHP child processes (depending on `php-fpm.conf`)

Comment: @IVOGELOV Not sure about PHP-FPM. Is that what `fastcgi_pass php_upstream;` is about?   When nginX launches, I see a number X of php-cgi.exe processes already waiting, and yes it's when we re-use the first/last one that it freezes. I'll add my php_upstream.conf to clarify.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Also, the calls are sequential, not simultaneous. I can't imagine requiring 75 processes to handle the small queries for a list of 75 items.

Comment: If I understand you correctly - you have 4 upstreams. Since you have no clue about PHP-FPM - I assume that these `php_cgi.exe` can not handle more than 1 request at any given time. So as soon as you have a 5th HTTP request while the previous 4 are still not completed - it will have to wait for a free upstream, right ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV Yes moslty, except only one php_cgi.exe will hang/timeout, the one making the other calls. The other 3 are free because they finish responding already: calls are not simultaneous. I know because my loop of 15 calls will continue after a 60sec timeout and use the other 3 and then hang again on the "1st", and so on.

Comment: Have you considered trying PHP-FPM ? It will avoid the blocking - so if you reach the limit it will simply return HTTP 503, immediately.

Comment: I have considered PHP_FPM, but my research says it is not available on Windows. Do you have information otherwise?

Comment: You may find these articles helpful - (1) http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-install-nginx-php-php-fpm-and-mysql-under-1616.html (2) https://www.pascallandau.com/blog/php-php-fpm-and-nginx-on-docker-in-windows-10/#setup-php-fpm If I were you, I would have used a Linux-based VM where PHP-FPM is readily available ...